# Select an option from drop down in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown, html-select

I am facing a problem to select an option from the drop down.
The site is https://uk.farnell.com. There is an All drop down just before the Search text box. I want to select "Ceramic Capacitors" from the drop down.
I tried in may ways like using

1. Select sel = new Select(locator)
2. JavascriptExecutor
3. Actions
4. List
   But none worked.

[The image displays All has been clicked and Ceramic Capacitors is highlighted which I want to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EkVP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

xpath for All - `.//div[@id='catContainer']`

xpath for Ceramic Capacitors - `.//option[text()='Ceramic Capacitors']`

Answer (score 0):

Select by 3rd index or by visible text.

```
driver.get('https://uk.farnell.com/')
Select(driver.find_element_by_id('categoryIdBox')).select_by_index(3)
Select(driver.find_element_by_id('categoryIdBox')).select_by_visible_text("Ceramic Capacitors")
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
WebElement dropdownlist=Driver.findElement(By.id("categoryIdBox"));
Select listbox = new Select(dropdownlist);
listbox.selectByVisibleText("Ceramic Capacitors");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code it might help to resolve your issue

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//div[@id='catContainer']//following-sibling::select))"));
    
Select selectOption = new Select(element);
selectOption.selectByIndex(3);
    
WebElement option = selectOption.getFirstSelectedOption();

* This is used just to verify the selected option
System.out.println(option.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code:

```
Select options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='categoryIdBox']")));
options.selectByVisibleText("Ceramic Capacitors");
```